# Laravel websocket is getting error when i send a message from my JS client

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-6, phpwebsocket, laravel-websockets

Im building a websocket service in my Laravel app versión 6.2, and using the laravel-websockets package version 1.3 (https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets).

So, it works fine, but im customizing my websocket to according the documentation to redefine onOpen, onClose, onError and onMessage methods. After this, i test with a client all of them methods and they still to works fine (onOpen, onClose, onError), except onMessage method, this last execute the following exception:

```
Exception `ErrorException` thrown: `Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$app`
Unknown app id: exception `ErrorException` thrown: `Undefined property: Ratchet\Server\IoConnection::$app`.
```

I dont know whats Happening, but here is me custom websocket class to catch the client events:

```
<?php

namespace App\Websocket;

use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\MessageComponentInterface;

class Handler implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onOpen() method.
        \Log::debug('ON OPEN');
        // \Log::debug([$connection]);
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onClose() method.
        \Log::debug('ON CLOSE');
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, \Exception $e)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onError() method.
        \Log::debug('ON ERROR');
        // \Log::debug([$connection]);
        \Log::debug($e);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, MessageInterface $msg)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onMessage() method.
        \Log::debug('ON MESSAGE');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here [beyondcode/laravel-websockets issue #342](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/342#issuecomment-606754915)
You have to create an instance of app attribute at onOpen method, here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Websocket;

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\App;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\MessageComponentInterface;

class Handler implements MessageComponentInterface
{

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onOpen() method.
        \Log::debug('ON OPEN');
        $socketId = sprintf('%d.%d', random_int(1, 1000000000), random_int(1, 1000000000));
        $connection->socketId = $socketId;
        $connection->app = App::findById('YOUR_APP_ID');
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onClose() method.
        \Log::debug('ON CLOSE');
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, \Exception $e)
    {
        // TODO: Implement onError() method.
        \Log::debug('ON ERROR');
        // \Log::debug([$connection]);
        // \Log::debug($e);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, MessageInterface $msg)
    {
        $connection->send('Hello World!');
        // TODO: Implement onMessage() method.
        \Log::debug(['ON MESSAGE', $msg]);
    }
}
```

Sure, you hace to customize a Service provider to init the application socket data, here is the documentation: [Custom App Providers](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/advanced-usage/app-providers.html)

Comment: what to pass in $connection->app = App::findById('YOUR_APP_ID'); in this line what to pass in YOUR_APP_ID